# Run ab-initio graph through java?

Tags: java, shell, unix, ab-initio

I'm trying to create a java based automated testing framework where users can run ab-initio graphs and compare results.

Is it possible to execute an ab-initio graph through java?

There's an AIR SANDBOX command in unix which I believe can be used to execute ab-initio graphs. How do I get this setup and how do I run this command through my java code?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the function `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping google.com")` will execute a Unix program of your choice. For Ab Initio, you'll want to call air sandbox followed by all of your graph input parameters and whatnot.

The linked tutorial will explain to you in greater depth how to use `exec()` and the returned process. 
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/